# В чем необходимость рефлексии в golang?

Tags: golang

Рефлексия это способность приложения исследовать свою структуру. Пример, как я понял: приходит некая структура и мы можем установить ее поля, теги и значения (может что то ещё). Посыл таков, что мы получаем гибкий инструмент, для работы.

Не могу понять, что оно вообще даёт? Ну пришла какая то непонятная структура нам, ну установим мы о ней все что нужно, ну а что дальше то? Эти знания непонятно как применять дальше

Есть одно предложение, что возможна такая ситуация: нам нужно из структуры достать поле Name, например. Мы точно знаем его смысл. И вот мы шаримся используя рефлексию по структуре, в поисках этого Name и его значения. 
Но это вообще как то неестественно... Разве не легче жёстко описать прикладной протокол со своими четко описанными структурами и прочим, чтобы не оставить никаким клиентам возможности отправлять посылки в виде структур с рандомными полями и прочим

Comment: представьте что вам нужно сериализовать (сохранить в файл значения) любой структуры, которая передана в вашу функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт именно о прикладном протоколе, то как вы добьётесь его максимально удобного использования, если у вас будут четко зафиксированные заголовки? Возьмём например **HTTP**, у **HTTP** что в запросе что в ответе есть ряд обязательных заголовков, но в **HTTP** при этом есть ещё десятки необязательных заголовков. При этом каждый разработчик, может настроить веб-сервер так что если в запросе не будет какого-то необязательного заголовка, будет ошибка. И это я ещё не беру в расчёт пользовательские заголовки ответа. Бес расширяемости, вы не добьётесь такого результата. Четко фиксированные заголовки(не больше не меньше) полезны только в кооперативных прикладных протоколах, о которых каждый пользователь(клиент, сервер) знает на все сто процентов. Если речь идёт про структуры.

Comment: А если отправили http с кучей необязательных заголовков, мы будем доставать при помощи рефлексии только те заголовки которые нам известны? Разве можно что то делать с неизвестными до этого момента нам заголовками? Или можно, узнавая новые заголовки, как то переориентировать программу?

Comment: Сам по себе, человек в том же HTTP может послать вам хоть «кеклолчебурек», а вы будете парсить только те заголовки, которые вам нужны. Тоже самое и с вашей программой, ваша программа может корректно работать и с одним заголовоком `test` Например, но она приймит и все пользовательские заголовки вроде `test-num-N`.

Comment: Если вас устроит ответ, установите соотвестующую галку, так вы поможете всем кто в дальнейшем будет изучать этот вопрос.

Comment: А не могли бы ещё момент подсказать один... получается что чтобы добавить гибкости в веб сервис, мы должны распарсить ЛЮБОЙ полученный json используя рефлексию? Т.е. распаковка через анмаршал не подходит, т.к. с ней сервис становится ущербным. Рефлексия дело относительно долгое, чем обычный анмаршал, и сервис будет тормозить..

Comment: Да, все верно. Чтобы сервер не тормозил вы должны сделать его асинхронным по колбэку, поясняю, на ваш сервер приходит запрос, вы сразу отгадаете ответ Типа «ОК начинаем работу, вот тебе ID твоей задачи», сам сервер в это время помещает задачу которая пришла от клиента в очередь, в потом по таймеру или воркеру запускается процесс, который разбирает задачу(JSON) например, а когда-то закончит, он посылает в запросе к тому кто прислал задачу, результат. Таким образом не наш сервер не клиент не уходят в блокирующий режим, и мы добиваемся ассинхронности.